# ios adding audio to buttons

Tags: ios, audio

hi does anyone know how to add audio to buttons i have added the framework creatd an action that place the sounds but when i press the button no sound plays?

heres what i have done so far

```
-(void)buttonSound{


    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/ButtonSound.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

    NSError *error;
    audioPlayer2 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    audioPlayer2.numberOfLoops = -1;

    [audioPlayer2 play];

}

- (IBAction)backToMenu:(id)sender {
    [self buttonSound];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your audioplayer is getting released by immediately popping up navigation controller.

if you remove this line:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

you should be able to hear the audio file (if the path is correct).

Comment: ooh..someone looks angry..with the answer

Answer (score 1):

For short system sounds, you should use something like:

```
SystemSoundID sound;
CFURLRef alertURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), (CFStringRef)@"ButtonSound", CFSTR("mp3"), NULL);
OSStatus status = AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(alertURL, &sound);

AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(sound);
```

Comment: you will not be able to control the volume once audio starts - if AudioServices are used and it should be a small duration sound ~30 secs as per apple.

Comment: @samfisher the OP's question stated "how to add audio to buttons" - I took that to mean for example a click when the a button is pressed, so should be fairly short.